# javascript recursive function falling in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have following recursive function which should call itself unless coordinates goes beyond DOM table or unless distance between starting point and point of current recursion is greater than distance given by user. However function falls into infinite loop switching infinitely between several points and I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

```
function fillSquare(a,b,dist){
    var xStart = parseInt(a);
    var yStart = parseInt(b);
    var distance = dist;

    function fill(c,d){
        var x = parseInt(c);
        var y = parseInt(d);

        if(x<0 || y<0 || x>boardWidth-1 || y>boardHeight-1){
            return;
        }else if(getDistance(cells[getFieldId(xStart,yStart)], cells[getFieldId(x,y)]) > dist){
            return;
        }else{
            cells[getFieldId(x,y)].hasWall = false;
            document.getElementById(x+'x'+y).backgroundColor = 'gray';
            console.log(x+' '+y);

            fill(x-1,y);
            fill(x+1,y);
            fill(x,y-1);
            fill(x,y+1);
        }
    }

    fill(xStart,yStart);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a function within a function. Do you mean to do that?

Comment: @Matt Cremeens Yes. xStart and yStart should have same value  during whole process (so inner fill function can compare starting point (with coordinates xStart and yStart) and point after n-th recursion and return distance between them. I have no idea how to do that in different way.

Comment: @Iven Yes I think so... my goal was to make flood fill algorithm with additional condition...

Comment: It looks like you might just be running into some off-by-one errors in your first if statement.  Have you tried taking away the -1 to boardWidth and boardHeight?

Comment: I don't understand - `fill(x,y+1);` will be called again by the recursive `fill(x,y-1);` call and vice versa. There are tons of multiple calls. This function is just wrong in so many ways

Comment: @Brice Garlick Yes, it won't help. Js Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4z4bq37s/

Comment: What @AlonEitan says makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You need to check whether the current element was already filled, and return. That way, when it gets back to the same element from a different direction, the recursion will stop.

Comment: You should include the link to your fiddle directly in your question.  That way people don't ask for the definition of `cells` and `getDistance`.

Comment: Your fiddle has a link to an external file that isn't accessible by the fiddle - so it won't run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the recursive calls will go back to the same elements. For instance, when you do `fill(4, 5)`, it calls `fill(x-1, y)`, which is `fill(3, 5)`. Then that calls `fill(x+1, y)`, which goes back to `fill(4, 5)`. It will keep cycling between them.

You need to check whether you've already filled an element, and not repeat it.

```
function fill(c,d){
    var x = parseInt(c);
    var y = parseInt(d);

    if(cells[getFieldId(x, y)].hasWall === false || x<0 || y<0 || x>boardWidth-1 || y>boardHeight-1){
        return;
    }else if(getDistance(cells[getFieldId(xStart,yStart)], cells[getFieldId(x,y)]) > dist){
        return;
    }else{
        cells[getFieldId(x,y)].hasWall = false;
        document.getElementById(x+'x'+y).backgroundColor = 'gray';
        console.log(x+' '+y);

        fill(x-1,y);
        fill(x+1,y);
        fill(x,y-1);
        fill(x,y+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the rest of your code, what is the console output of this:

```
// for debugging
var i = 0;

// helper function to parse into integers
function fillSquare(xStart, yStart, distance)
{
    // kick it off
    // on the first run the current is the start
    fill(parseInt(xStart), parseInt(yStart), parseInt(xStart), parseInt(yStart), distance);
}

function fill(xCurrent, yCurrent, xStart, yStart, distance)
{
    // the next two lines are temporary just for debugging purposes
    ++i;
    if(i > 100) return;

    // log where we are so we can see progress
    console.log({ "xCurrent" : xCurrent, "yCurrent" : yCurrent, "xStart" : xStart, "yStart" : yStart, "distance" : distance, "getDistance" : getDistance(cells[getFieldId(xStart,yStart)], cells[getFieldId(xCurrent, yCurrent)]) });

    // no need to parse since you did that on the initial run and the recursive calls are all basic math

    if(xCurrent < 0 || yCurrent < 0 || xCurrent > boardWidth - 1 || yCurrent > boardHeight - 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(getDistance(cells[getFieldId(xStart,yStart)], cells[getFieldId(xCurrent, yCurrent)]) > distance)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cells[getFieldId(xCurrent,yCurrent)].hasWall = false;
        document.getElementById(xCurrent + 'x' + yCurrent).backgroundColor = 'gray';

        fill(xCurrent - 1, yCurrent, xStart, yStart, distance)
        fill(xCurrent + 1, yCurrent, xStart, yStart, distance)
        fill(xCurrent, yCurrent - 1, xStart, yStart, distance)
        fill(xCurrent, yCurrent + 1, xStart, yStart, distance)
    }
}
```